# Why are floats converted to NaN in a Pandas Dataframe when using date as index?

Tags: python, pandas, date, dataframe, floating-point

### Original Question

I am trying to create a Pandas Dataframe, but a column consisted of floats continues to go wrong because of the adjusted index column. As long as I set a DatetimeIndex as the index column, all floats will be converted to NaN.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)
s = pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':s,},index=dates)
df.head()

            A    
2013-01-01  NaN
2013-01-02  NaN
2013-01-03  NaN
2013-01-04  NaN
```

I have tried what I cand do. As soon as the index is set in default, the floats can show up normally.

```
s = pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':s,})
df.head()

    A
0   1.0
1   1.0
2   1.0
3   1.0
```

Please help!
I am a newbie to Python so it's important for me to understand why this can go wrong. Thank you!

### Update Jul 22, 2019, 1:46 PM （UTC+8）

@Andy L. thank you! your suggestion can solve the problem elegantly.

Nevertheless, I still want to figure out the exact reason behind this.

@WeNYoBen thanks for explaining! I tried to drop the specified index in s and it still won't work.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)
s = pd.Series((1,1,1,1),dtype='float32')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':s,},index=dates)
df.head() 

            A    
2013-01-01  NaN
2013-01-02  NaN
2013-01-03  NaN
2013-01-04  NaN
```

However, if I use regular list instead of the pandas series, it works well.

```
dates = pd.date_range('20130101', periods=4)
s = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':s,},index=dates)
df.head() 

             A    
2013-01-01  1.0
2013-01-02  1.0
2013-01-03  1.0
2013-01-04  1.0
```

I am wondering if the problem lies in the specific type pd.Series.

Comment: try: `pd.DataFrame({'A':s.values,},index=dates)`

Comment: Data frame will match the index first , your s have range index , can not match with df datetime like index

Comment: Thanks to you two cool ppl, especially @AndyL.!! It's fixed! I appreciate it!